# Segfault (-11) on program exit

Tags: linux, segmentation-fault, g++, gtkmm

I'm trying to get `goocanvasmm` working from a C++ program. From a couple
of places I combined code snippets and got the program to draw.

However, on program termination, a segfault appears. I'm not a normal `C++` user,
and as such, the `gdb` messages are somewhat cryptic to me.

Here's the code. It creates a window, and draws a 200x200 pixel yellow square in it:

```
#include <gtkmm.h>
#include <goocanvasmm.h>
#include <iostream>
#define UI_FILE "gtk_foobar.ui"

int
main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
  Gtk::Main kit(argc, argv);

  //Load the Glade file and instiate its widgets:
  Glib::RefPtr<Gtk::Builder> builder;
  try {
    builder = Gtk::Builder::create_from_file(UI_FILE);
  }
  catch (const Glib::FileError & ex) {
    std::cerr << ex.what() << std::endl;
    return 1;
  }
  
  Gtk::Window *main_win = 0;
  builder->get_widget("main_window", main_win);
  
  Goocanvas::Canvas canvas;
  
  main_win->add(canvas);
  auto root = (canvas).get_root_item();
  auto rect = Goocanvas::Rect::create(100, 100, 200, 200);
  
  rect->property_stroke_color() = "yellow";
  rect->property_line_width() = 3;
  root->add_child(rect);
  
  main_win->show_all();

  if (main_win) {
    kit.run(*main_win);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

the run-time error message (shown on program termination):

```
Program has been terminated receiving signal 11 (Segmentation fault)
```

and the `gdb` backtrace:

```
#0  0x00007ffff5ae7d6c in free () at /lib64/libc.so.6
#1  0x00007ffff5a97736 in __cxa_finalize () at /lib64/libc.so.6
#2  0x00007ffff7d22946 in __do_global_dtors_aux () at /usr/lib64/libgoocanvasmm-2.0.so.6
#3  0x00007ffff7ffd060 in _rtld_local () at /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
#4  0x0000000000000000 in  ()
```

If I'm not mistaken, this seems to indicate a problem with the destructors in
`libgoocanvasmm`.

**Edit:** I realized (a little late) that, to run the application, it's also necessary to have the `UIFILE`. Here it is ("gtk_foobar.ui"):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<interface>
  <!-- interface-naming-policy project-wide -->
  <!-- interface-requires gtk+ 3.0 -->
  <object class="GtkWindow" id="main_window">
    <property name="visible">True</property>
    <property name="title" translatable="yes">Hello World!</property>
    <property name="default_width">500</property>
    <property name="default_height">400</property>
    <child>
      <placeholder/>
    </child>
  </object>
</interface>
```

To make things easier, [this link](https://www.sendspace.com/file/8d7fpp) will download the complete `autotools` project.

Comment: Did you try to code `main_win = nullptr;` just before the `return 0;` in your `main` ?

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch: No change - still segfaults. Thanks!

Comment: Did you try to use [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) ?

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch, Yes... The results are a little cryptic. Though Valgrid (rightly) reports some memory leaks, I can find no reference to issues which could lead to segfaults.

Comment: [GooCanvas](https://sourceforge.net/projects/goocanvas/) looks like an unmaintained open source project. Did you try to download its source code and compile it yourself with `gcc -O -g` ? If your code is not too big, consider using [Qt](https://qt.io/) instead. Another possibility might be to use Ian Taylor's [libbacktrace](https://github.com/ianlancetaylor/libbacktrace) and to catch `SIGSEGV`. See [signal(7)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html) and [signal-safety(7)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal-safety.7.html)

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch, Yes, GooCanvas is somewhat orphaned, but I have some contacts with (one of) the authors. Also, it's the 'canvas' I've found for Gtk. I did compile it myself, but didn't add `-g -O0`. That could be useful. Note that I use GooCanvas frequently in Python with Object introspection (so it's the same library), without any issues. Note that the lib is in the Gnome project as stable.

Comment: Thanks to your reproducible example, I could build and run your program. I was using Ubuntu with GCC. To build it, I installed the [`libgoocanvasmm`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/libgoocanvasmm-2.0-dev) items in the official Ubuntu repository. When running your program, I noticed no segfaults, even upon quitting. It seems to be related to the specific build you are using, or maybe the plateform you are running it on. What version of goocanvas are you building, on that OS?

Comment: @BobMorane Exactly the same question I wanted to ask. pkg-config reports 1.90.9, but somewhere I read 2.0.6. I now see that in the Ubuntu repo, version is 1.90.11, but the package is actually 2.0.6 too? Anyway, I found the .11 source at  https://download-fallback.gnome.org/sources/goocanvasmm/1.90/, compiled and the error is gone! Thanks for your testing!

Comment: No need to put "solved"in the title - just accept your answer once the system lets you

Comment: @WaiHaLee Does this also change entries in the search engines?

Comment: To be perfectly honest, I don't know. I would be amazed if it didn't - Stack Overflow has been around for ages. I had a look on Meta to see if I could find anything but other than that [it shouldn't be done](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/116101/284827) I can't find anything specific to search engines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @BobMorane who tested the program and found a minor version difference between libraries. It seems that both my source package and his are labeled 2.0.6, but internally there's a minor difference, 1.90.9 and 1.90.11, which was important.

Recompiling with the 1.90.11 version solved the problem!

Checking the Changelog showed no world-shocking differences, but a series of minor compatibility updates. Re-running valgrind did show the disappearance of this message:

```
==30082== Invalid free() / delete / delete[] / realloc()
==30082==    at 0x483B71B: operator delete(void*) (vg_replace_malloc.c:802)
==30082==    by 0x6C25735: __cxa_finalize (in /lib64/libc-2.30.so)
==30082==    by 0x48FB945: ??? (in /usr/lib64/libgoocanvasmm-2.0.so.6.0.0)
==30082==    by 0x4914FC0: ??? (in /usr/lib64/libgoocanvasmm-2.0.so.6.0.0)
==30082==    by 0x6C25016: __run_exit_handlers (in /lib64/libc-2.30.so)
==30082==    by 0x6C251C9: exit (in /lib64/libc-2.30.so)
==30082==    by 0x6C03E61: (below main) (in /lib64/libc-2.30.so)
==30082==  Address 0x8 is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd
```